# Trying to use function from external .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `import DiGraph` to import my external file and trying to run the following code:

`prediction = DiGraph.remove_duplicates(make_trips(G, source='c1', target=['c2', 'c3']))`

but I get `NameError: name 'make_trips' is not defined`

All the names are how they appear in my external file and it is even identical code besides the prediction =. What am I missing?

*Edit:
Thanks, Gilch, Kartikeya Sharma, and Nishat for the explanations.

Comment: `import DiGraph` brings up everything that is a defined inside the `DiGraph` module (sub-modules needs to be imported explicitly), but you still need to access it as `DiGraph.<name>` to access it. You did that for `remove_duplicates`; you also need to do that for `make_trips` (from wherever is available). The other alternative is `from DiGraph import remove_duplicates` which bringing directly to the namespace without adding the extra `DiGraph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `DiGraph.make_trips`?

Importing like that only gives you the one module object; it doesn't dump its contents into the current namespace. (You could use `from DiGraph import *` for that, but star imports get confusing fast, so they're generally not recommended.)

> Now I get NameError: name 'G' is not defined. 'G' is a variable at the top of the file. How should I handle this? Thanks

At the top of the DiGraph file? You can do it the same way. `DiGraph.G`.

If `DiGraph` is too much to type, you can do

```
import DiGraph as dg
```

instead of `import DiGraph`. Then you can refer to the `DiGraph` module as `dg` instead, e.g.

```
prediction = dg.remove_duplicates(dg.make_trips(dg.G, source='c1', target=['c2', 'c3']))
```

Comment: Thanks, DiGraph.make_trips was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can import your external function like this

```
from <module> import <function>
```

So if your make_trip function is inside make_trip.py file then you can import like this

```
from make_trip import make_trip
```

Comment: I would word it as `from <module> import <name>`. It doesn't have to be a function. It could be a class, or a "constant", or anything defined at the module's top level (globals).

Comment: You that's correct but for the understanding w.r.t to this program I thought of including function only